# Можно ли писать на Kotlin, без особых знаний Java?

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть опыт со скриптовыми языками (Ruby, Python), a Kotlin много чего у них позаимствовал. Язык мне понравился в плане простоты как Ruby.

Comment: Можно, но это еще тяжелее. Примеров использования разных API еще очень мало на котлине. Та же хрень со всеми кроссплатформенными инструментами.

Answer (score 6):

Писать можно, но на данный момент без полной изоляции от Java нереально. Ведь сами подумайте все базовые классы на Java и уйти от этого требуется время, да и зачем? Многие либы, многие решения не сопровождаются до сих пор котлином, большинство решений разных проблем в сети будут скорей всего на java.

Но если мыслить с точки зрения могу ли я писать приложения не используя Java? - то тогда, да без сомнения.